# Nginx: simple page redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

I'd like to make two simple 301 page redirections.

For example:

`http://domain.com/example.php?var=value`

and:

`http://domain.com/some-page`

Both redirecting to:

`http://domain.com/index.htm`

Which is the index of the domain.

I tried:

```
location / {
    index index.htm index.php;
    rewrite example.php?var=value / permanent;
}
```

But it is not working...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put (out of "location / {}"):

`rewrite /example.php?var=value / permanent;`

Or better:

`rewrite /example.php?(.*) / permanent;`

By the way, PHP has a way to make redirections 301 also.